# How can you split a huge scatter plot graph on Microsoft Excel into two graphs? (Mac)

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel

I'm doing a maths assignment and have a huge graph that I need to split into two somehow.

If you split my graph into quadrants, quadrant 2 would have all my data and quadrant 4 would have the forecasted trend until it hits a certain *y* value, so one of the graphs would be of my data and the second graph would be of the forecast (it's a linear negative line).

Currently, my graph is sized to be a little over 16 columns (normal size) across and ~44 rows down. I need it to be this huge because some of the data points are really close together (they were given to me randomly :/) and it's hard to distinguish between them with a smaller scale.

I'm not exactly sure what version of Excel I have, but the about page says it's version 16.33 and it's copyrighted as © 2019 Microsoft. The app logo is [this one](https://www.ecosia.org/images/?q=excel%20logo#id=F30B61DBB5979D258B5E03ADF1F2F157510B115D).

I'd appreciate any help I can get. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

nvm i figured out a way lol

copy the graph → paste the graph → change the axes to be confined to the chosen corner → that's graph one

and simply repeat for graph two. really living up to my dn rn